# How to get elements where data-ZZZ is not blank

Tags: jquery

I've got html that looks something like:

```
<div id="1" class="lineItem" data-options="">Line1</div>
<div id="2" class="lineItem" data-options="{size: M;}">Line2</div>
<div id="3" class="lineItem" data-options="{color: black;}">Line3</div>
```

Can I construct some sort of selector to just get `<div id="2">` and `<div id="3">`?

Something like:

```
$('.lineItem[data-options='not blank']')
```

Is this possible, or do I have to go through each of the DIVs manually to check that the data-options attribute isn't blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:not` selector

```
$('.lineItem[data-options]:not([data-options=""])');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QJuL7/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.lineItem').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).attr('data-options').length;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ELhy3/).

This does, though, look at each element returned by the selector, and assesses the `data-options` attribute to check that it's *not* empty (or, explicitly, that it has a length greater than `0`).

Comment: This will give an error if there are `.lineItem` without `data-options` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

use this selector

```
$(".lineItem[data-options!='']")
```